Automatically scale text size into bounding box area
I'm trying to center a text within a rectangle according to its height and width, but it comes out off-center. Additionally, I need the text to adjust according to the size of this rectangle. However, I'm not finding very good solutions.
Would anyone know where the error might be?
Result:

My code for help:
@Composable
internal fun ScreenShotDrawSpeech(
    bubbleDomain: ImmutableList<SpeechBubbleDomain>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val zoom = rememberZoomableState()

    Canvas(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .zoomable(zoom),
        onDraw = {
            bubbleDomain.forEach { prediction ->
                drawSpeechBoundingBox(text = prediction.originalText, boundingBox = prediction.rect, textMeasurer = textMeasurer)
            }
        },
    )
}
private fun DrawScope.drawSpeechBoundingBox(
    boundingBox: Rect,
    text: String,
    textMeasurer: TextMeasurer,
) {
    val currentWidth = textMeasurer.measure(text).size.width
    val currentHeight = textMeasurer.measure(text).size.height
    val desiredWidth = boundingBox.width()
    val desiredHeight = boundingBox.height()

    val centerTextY = (boundingBox.height() - currentHeight) / 2.5

    val font = calculateScaledFontSize(
        currentWidth = currentWidth,
        currentHeight = currentHeight,
        desiredWidth = desiredWidth,
        desiredHeight = desiredHeight,
        minFontSize = 12.sp.toPx(),
        maxFontSize = 14.sp.value,
        text = text,
    )

    val style = TextStyle(
        fontSize = font.sp,
        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.manga_master_bb)),
        color = Color.Black,
        background = Color.White,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
    )

    drawOval(
        color = Color.White,
        topLeft = Offset(boundingBox.left.toFloat(), boundingBox.top.toFloat()),
        size = Size(boundingBox.width().toFloat(), boundingBox.height().toFloat()),
    )
    drawOval(
        color = Color.Black,
        style = Stroke(width = 2f),
        topLeft = Offset(boundingBox.left.toFloat(), boundingBox.top.toFloat()),
        size = Size(boundingBox.width().toFloat(), boundingBox.height().toFloat()),
    )
    drawText(
        textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
        style = style,
        size = Size(boundingBox.width().toFloat(), boundingBox.height().toFloat()),
        topLeft = Offset(
            boundingBox.left.toFloat(),
            boundingBox.top.toFloat() + centerTextY.toFloat(),
        ),
        text = text.uppercase(),
    )
}

@Suppress("LongParameterList")
private fun calculateScaledFontSize(
    currentWidth: Int,
    currentHeight: Int,
    desiredWidth: Int,
    desiredHeight: Int,
    minFontSize: Float,
    maxFontSize: Float,
    text: String,
): Float {
    val widthScaleFactor = minFontSize * desiredWidth / currentWidth
    val heightScaleFactor = minFontSize * desiredHeight / currentHeight

    return if (min(widthScaleFactor, heightScaleFactor) >= maxFontSize) {
        if (text.length <= 10) {
            min(widthScaleFactor, heightScaleFactor) / 3
        } else {
            min(widthScaleFactor, heightScaleFactor) / 2
        }
    } else {
        min(widthScaleFactor, heightScaleFactor)
    }
}


You're calculating the Y-coordinate for centering the text using a fixed value 2.5 which can cause the text to be off-center.
@Composable
internal fun ScreenShotDrawSpeech(
    bubbleDomain: ImmutableList<SpeechBubbleDomain>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val zoom = rememberZoomableState()

    Canvas(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .zoomable(zoom),
        onDraw = {
            bubbleDomain.forEach { prediction ->
                drawSpeechBoundingBox(text = prediction.originalText, boundingBox = prediction.rect, textMeasurer = textMeasurer)
            }
        },
    )
}

private fun DrawScope.drawSpeechBoundingBox(
    boundingBox: Rect,
    text: String,
    textMeasurer: TextMeasurer,) 
{
    val currentSize = textMeasurer.measure(text).size
    val desiredSize = Size(boundingBox.width(), boundingBox.height())

    // Calculate the font size to fit both width and height
    val font = calculateScaledFontSize(currentSize, desiredSize)

    val style = TextStyle(
        fontSize = font.sp,
        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.manga_master_bb)),
        color = Color.Black,
        background = Color.White,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
    )

    // Draw bounding box
    drawOval(
        color = Color.White,
        topLeft = Offset(boundingBox.left.toFloat(), boundingBox.top.toFloat()),
        size = Size(boundingBox.width().toFloat(), boundingBox.height().toFloat()),
    )
    drawOval(
        color = Color.Black,
        style = Stroke(width = 2f),
        topLeft = Offset(boundingBox.left.toFloat(), boundingBox.top.toFloat()),
        size = Size(boundingBox.width().toFloat(), boundingBox.height().toFloat()),
    )

    // Calculate the position to center the text within the bounding box
    val centerTextX = boundingBox.left + (boundingBox.width() - currentSize.width * font) / 2
    val centerTextY = boundingBox.top + (boundingBox.height() - currentSize.height * font) / 2

    // Draw text centered within the bounding box
    drawIntoCanvas {
        it.nativeCanvas.drawText(
            text.uppercase(),
            centerTextX,
            centerTextY,
            Paint().apply {
                this.textSize = font.sp
                this.color = Color.Black.toArgb()
                this.typeface = Typeface.create(Font(R.font.manga_master_bb).toFamily().first(), Typeface.BOLD)
            }
        )
    }

//Updated font scaling function
private fun calculateScaledFontSize(
        currentSize: Size,
        desiredSize: Size,
    ): Float {
        val widthScaleFactor = desiredSize.width / currentSize.width
        val heightScaleFactor = desiredSize.height / currentSize.height
        // Choose the smaller scale factor to ensure the text fits within the bounding box
        val scaleFactor = min(widthScaleFactor, heightScaleFactor)
        // Cap the scale factor to avoid excessive font enlargement
            return min(1f, scaleFactor) // Adjust the cap value as needed
    }

I have updated your code with sample I was having from in code, please give it a try.

Hi! Thank you for the response.
That almost worked, but it seems it still doesn't center very well.
When the sentence is too short, it exaggerates the font size, and in some cases, the text exceeds the measurements.
Code: https://vicepad.com/text-align
Here are examples:
1: https://prnt.sc/B13C_Cc5KnNl
2: https://prnt.sc/I9Dw7Lq8XHDK

@OliverDamon I have made some changes to center the text. Also added cap to the font scale factor to prevent excessive font enlargement. Hope this will work.
